# Parsing Json to Java

Tags: java, json, apache-camel

```
{
  "customer": {
    "ssoId":"B56789",
    "brand":"123-reg",
    "forename":"John",
    "surname":"Doe",
    "title":"Mr",
    "companyName":"Unilever",
    "primaryEmail":"john.doe@unilever.com",
    "currency":"$",
    "language":"English",
    "vatNumber":"D4531234",
    "vatCode":"12B6",
    "ipAddress":"127.0.0.1"
  }
}
```

That's my JSON file I'm trying to unmarshal using Apache camel to a POJO but it keeps throwing that error! When I add the `@JsonIngoreProperties`, it returns a null object without populating the POJO.

```
@Data
@JsonInclude(NON_EMPTY)
public final class Customer{
    @JsonProperty(value = "ssoId", required = true)
    private String ssoId;

    @JsonProperty(value = "brand", required = true)
    private String brand;

    @JsonProperty(value = "forename", required = true)
    private String forename;
    //......
}
```

> ```
> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
> Unrecognized field "customer" (class com.heg.esb.model.Customer), not
> marked as ignorable (17 known properties: "addresses", "phones",
> "brand", "companyName", "ssoId", "ipAddress", "currency", "vatNumber",
> "vatCode", "title", "primaryEmail", "surname", "lastVerificationDate",
> "forename", "lastModifiedDate", "createdDate", "language"])
>  at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@3844c08b; line: 2, column: 16] (through reference chain: com.heg.esb.model.Customer["customer"])
>  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:51)
>  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:839)
>  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1045)
>  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1352)
>  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1330)
>  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:264)
>  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:125)
>  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3736)
>  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2796)
>  at org.apache.camel.component.jackson.JacksonDataFormat.unmarshal(JacksonDataFormat.java:173)
>  at org.apache.camel.processor.UnmarshalProcessor.process(UnmarshalProcessor.java:69)
>  at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
>  at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)
>  at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
>  at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
>  at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
>  at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:117)
>  at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
>  at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)
>  at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
>  at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
>  at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
>  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
>  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:112)
> ```

Comment: It looks like that there is `customer` field in `Customer` class without annotated with either @JsonProperty or @JsonIgnore?

Comment: That's not meant to be a property but what I need to use in my Jsonpath within camel blueprint to identify with POJO it should marshall it to.

Comment: Oh! I just noticed it was marked duplicate. Well, it wasn't as I had looked at the link added before posting it. I was asking how to transform the JSON file above to POJO as JSON was complaining about the outer "customer" before the curly brackets because it needed a wrapper class to understand what to do with the file. I used this website to solve my challenge "http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/"

Answer (score 0):

You need to have public setters in the POJO for each private field you're trying to have Jackson populate.

Also, you do not need to specify "value" in the @JsonProperty annotation if it's the same as the field name.

Comment: The @Data from lombok provides the getters and setters automatically. I couldn't include the "required" parameter without that.